# How do to create string ciphers

Tags: c#

I have an error on this part `foreach( string code in text )` the error is saying can not convert char to string. how do i convert this to string

my list

```
 class MyCipher : ICipherDecipher
    {
        private List<Code> alphabet;

        public MyCipher()
        {
            alphabet = new List<Code>();

            alphabet.Add(new Code("Aca", " 1234"));
            alphabet.Add(new Code("Bb", " 1234"));
            alphabet.Add(new Code("C1", " 1234"));
        }
```

this is where im gtting the error on the `foreach` part , its saying cant convert to string from char

```
 private string Cipher( string text )
        {
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

            foreach( string code in text )
            {
                Code element =
                    alphabet.Where(x => x.MyCode == code.ToString()).SingleOrDefault();

                if ( element != null)
                {
                    result.Append(element.MyDecoded);
                }
            }


            return result.ToString();

        }
```

***Edited code***

```
      class MyCipher : ICipherDecipher
    {
        private List<Code> alphabet;

        public MyCipher()
        {
            alphabet = new List<Code>();

            alphabet.Add(new Code("4", " take 4"));
            alphabet.Add(new Code(" ", " a"));
            alphabet.Add(new Code("4d", " for 4 days"));
        }

        public string Cipher(params string[] codes)
        {
           
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (string code in codes)
            {
                Code element =
                    alphabet.Where(x => x.MyCode == code).SingleOrDefault();

                if (element != null)
                {
                    result.Append(element.MyDecoded);
                }
            }

            return result.ToString();

        }


        class Code
        {
            public string MyCode;
            public string MyDecoded;
        


            public Code(string code, string decode)
            {
                MyCode = code;
                MyDecoded = decode;
            }

        }
    }
```

***Button code***

```
   public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        private ICipherDecipher myCipher;
        public Form1()
        {
            myCipher = new MyCipher();
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string textToBeCiphered = textBox1.Text;
            string textCiphered = myCipher.Cipher(textToBeCiphered);
            textBox2.Text = textCiphered;
        }
    }
```

Comment: im new guys, please help

Comment: A string is a sequential collection of characters. you need to iterate by `char` not `string`. Can you  tell us what is value in `text`? I guess you are looking for `Contains()` or `StartsWith()` or `EndsWith()`

Comment: You are declaring `List<Code> alphabet` but using it as it were a dictionary. A `List<T>` can have duplicated values but a `Dictionary<S,T>` cannot. Your code would be more robust if you use `Dictionary<string, string> alphabet`. **Do note I assume that cipher is only an exercise/for fun**. For real scenarios you should not do that kind of manual cipher (it is not cryptologically robust)

Answer (score 0):

You're iterating over a string (`text`), so the `code` variable should be a `char`, not a `string`:

```cs
foreach( char code in text )
```

Alternatively, you can use `var`:

```cs
foreach( var code in text )
```

to make the compiler automatically assign the type it thinks it should be, but you should still be aware of the type it actually *is* because it impacts the operations the variable supports.

Going a bit deeper into it, some other languages (especially dynamic languages like JavaScript and Python) don't make this distinction but C# (like most other C-like languages) has a `char` datatype that holds a single element of the text. In the case of C#, that type holds a [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) code unit. (Which is not always the same as a user-visible character, but that's a whole *other* story).

---

Based on the discussion in the comments, it seems you want to match the whole string instead of characters of the string. In that case you have two options, depending on what you want to do:

If you want the Cypher method to receive a single string and get the code that matches that string, just get rid of the loop and match against the parameter directly:

```cs
        private string Cipher( string code )
        {
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

            Code element =
                alphabet.Where(x => x.MyCode == code).SingleOrDefault();

            if ( element != null)
            {
                result.Append(element.MyDecoded);
            }

            return result.ToString();
        }
```

Alternatively, if you want to pass *multiple* strings and process all of them, pass an `IEnumerable<string>` (from `System.Collections.Generic`) or a derived type such as `string[]`:

```cs
        private string Cipher( IEnumerable<string> codes )
        {
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

            foreach( string code in codes )
            {
                Code element =
                    alphabet.Where(x => x.MyCode == code).SingleOrDefault();

                if ( element != null)
                {
                    result.Append(element.MyDecoded);
                }
            }

            return result.ToString();

        }

        // Usage examples:
        private string CallSite() {
            // (These are just some of the options, other enumerable types
            // will work as well as long as they enumerate over strings)
            return Cypher( new[] { "Aca", "Bb" });
            return Cypher( new List<string> { "Aca", "Bb" });
        }
```

Alternatively, if you replace `IEnumerable<string>` with `params string[]` you can call the function as if it had any number of string parameters:

```cs
        private string Cipher( params string[] codes )
        {
            // ... (as above)
        }

        // Usage example:
        private string CallSite() {
            return Cypher( "Aca", "Bb" );
        }
```

In any of these cases, you can get replace `code.ToString()` with simply `code` because it already *is* a string (and `"string".ToString()` just returns itself).

Comment: what variable should i use on (text) that will accept string, i dont want to use char in this case

Comment: If you don't want to use `char` you need to explain what you expect the `code` variable to contain relative to `text`...

Comment: i want the Cipher program to accept strings not single char. In this case if i use char the value ` Aca` in list wont give a value since it is a string not char

Comment: i want code to accept strings but i am failing to do it , help please

Comment: i posted the whole code below, instead of writing text what should i use to represent string

Comment: the code now accepts the string but im not understanding `private string CallSite()`. So now when i type another code infront of "Aca" nothing is showing, its like its not appending, thats what im left with thank you.

Comment: can you see the edited code above on my question, thank you

Comment: The `CallSite` is just an example of how it could be called, it's not needed.

Comment: Remove the `params object[]` overload, and since you've picked the `params string[]` variant from the above, don't use the `new List<string>` when calling it. That's what was causing it to use the `params object[]` variant, which then can't pull out strings because it's getting an array containing a `List<string>` instead of a string.

Comment: Generally, a `params object[]` overload of another function that only does a cast and then calls the other function is often just a bad idea because it'll just hide errors, because it will accept anything you pass it and ignore it if it can't handle it.

Comment: Can You help me , i removed the `List<string>` im left using  ` List<Code>()` but its still not appending

Comment: how to remove `prams object[]` overload, and also how to make it append

Comment: Near the top you have `public string Cipher(params object[] arguments) { ... }`. Get rid of that, and just use the other one (the one with `params string[]`). Alternatively, if you call the other one with a *single* string (instead of a *list of* strings) it should also work.

Comment: i did so , but the code is not yet Appending, I edited my code above

Comment: how do i call the everything in the list because its not Appending

Comment: I just pasted your current (edited) code into a .cs file and called `Console.WriteLine(new MyCipher().Cipher("4", " ", "4d"));`. It printed `" take 4 a for 4 days"`. The only change I made was commenting out the interface so it would compile.

Comment: is it because of the code on my button, i was using 2 textboxes for this since its in winForms, im adding the code of the button on my question

Comment: i have added my button code, i enter the codes on `textbox1` and the results will appear on `textbox2`

Comment: If your textbox doesn't contain *just* the single MyCode value, you sould do something other than straight-up comparison. Maybe use something like [StringBuilder.Replace()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder.replace?view=netcore-3.1#System_Text_StringBuilder_Replace_System_String_System_String_) instead?

Answer (score 0):

Change this part of your code:

```
 foreach( char code in text )
   {
      Code element =
      alphabet.Where(x => x.MyCode == code.ToString()).SingleOrDefault();

      if ( element != null)
         {
             result.Append(element.MyDecoded);
         }
   }
```

Then everywhere you use code you convert it to string by using `code.ToString()`

Comment: hello thank you but i had originally used  ` foreach( char code in text )` but i want the code to accept string of text not char since `Aca` is a string not a single character

Comment: You see, the text in this case is a string "Aca" however, in a foreach statement, it will break this text into its separate chars. That is how foreach works with strings.

Comment: Alright i can see, so how best can i change the code so i can just call  "Aca" without the code breaking

Comment: I am not sure about what you want your code to do. That depends on what you want to achieve. However at the point where you are calling the Cypher Class, you may need to pass a List of the string. Could you explain what you want to achieve?

Comment: okay for example when i  type"Aca" then i type "Bb"  infront  the code for "Bb" should be appended to the value in "Aca"